# Is there a way to make an e-mail button that has an effect like a 3rd party tool?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, email

For now, I'm just using a basic javascript image button on each master page of my asp.net website.  The button, when clicked, opens up your default email client.  It's coded like this:

```
<td>
<input type="image" src="../images/button-email.jpg" id="btnEmail"  
onclick="parent.location='mailto: @.com?subject=Check out USS Vision'" value="Email" 
alt="Email this page" />
</td>
```

Is there a way, without using a 3rd party tool, where I can have an end-user click the e-mail button, and it opens up right in the web browser, more smoothly than finding your default email client?  I suppose I'm trying to get the same effect of a 3rd party tool without having to use a 3rd party tool and all the lag, external javascript files, etc., that come with a 3rd party tool.  I'm not sure if this is possible.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Button in your HTML code will open print window. How is that related to an e-mail? Are you talking about `mailto:`?

Comment: I apologize @FAngel; I was multitasking and put the wrong code in there.  I edited it.  But yes, I was talking about the mailto: ... it just can take 5-8,9 seconds to open up your default e-mail client, whereas the 3rd party tools like addthis are lighter and more smooth.  But I don't like all the garbage that comes with 3rd party tools.  Thanks for nothing that error I made in my post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible unless some user has installed email client plugin in his/her browser which is not a common solution. I would suggest to build a HTML form that will be submitted to the server which has configured POP3/SMTP.

Comment: Thanks @Adam Bubela.  I didn't think it was possible either, but just had to ask to make sure.  I had copied the wrong code (now corrected), but I just don't like all the extra garbage that comes with a 3rd party too like addthis or something similar.  They add too many http requests and slow page loading time.  I do have an html form, but that's only on the contact page.  We have 47 pages and a lot of products, and sometimes, engineers want to email that page, so I was looking for an easier way, but it appears there isn't one. Thank you for your time reading and responding to my question!

Comment: No worries Jason, glad I could help. " We have 47 pages and a lot of products, and sometimes, engineers want to email that page" - I guess you may need a newsletter system which hooked up to your database wold populate product information automatically. Usually the html pages don't look good in email clients as MS Outlook Express which meant that standard html needs to be simplified.

Comment: Well, I don't want the page itself e-mailed ... just an option to email the page to the end-user's recipient.  For instance, like on http://www.ussvision.com/about .... you'll see an e-mail button underneath the left navigational menu, with other social media buttons.  Instead of calling their default email client, I'd rather it just bring up a window that won't be as slow as the way I have it set up now.  Anyway, thanks for taking the time to look over my question, @adam bubela; I appreciate it!